# How do I stop using rsa key for git pull?

Tags: git, credentials, private-key, git-pull

The repository was cloned using a key, but now I need to do a pull using user and password authentication, and doing the git pull won't ask for credentials.

How do I force the pull to ask me for credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/OTHERREPOSITORY.git
```

Found it here:
https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/